# Tkinter TreeView binding left click to the current tree and selected item

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to bind this function self.copyTextToClipboard(self,t) to multiple different trees to make it more flexible (please see binding below). 
    from tkinter.ttk import Treeview
    from tkinter import *

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        frame = Frame(master)

        master.geometry("{}x{}".format(master.winfo_screenwidth() - 100, master.winfo_screenheight() - 100))
        master.resizable(False, False)

        self.leftFrame = Frame(master, bg="#DADADA", width=375, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.leftFrame.pack_propagate(0)
        self.leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=1)

        # This table (TreeView) will display the partitions in the tab
        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree = Treeview(self.leftFrame, columns=("#"), show="headings", selectmode="browse", height=23)

        yscrollB = Scrollbar(self.leftFrame)
        yscrollB.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.column("#", width=50)
        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.heading("#", text="#")
        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollB.set)

        # Bind left click on text widget to copy_text_to_clipboard() function
        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda t=self.partitionsOpenDiskTree: self.copyTextToClipboard(self,t))

        # Adding the entries to the TreeView
        for i in range(3):
            self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.insert("", "end", i, values=(i), tags=str(i))

        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.pack(anchor=NW, fill=Y)

    #todo: figure out where this is getting called and put in tree
    def copyTextToClipboard(self, tree, event=None):
        print(type(tree))
        # triggered off left button click on text_field
        root.clipboard_clear()  # clear clipboard contents
        textList = tree.item(tree.focus())["values"]
        line = ""
        for text in textList:
            if line != "":
                line += ", " + str(text)
            else:
                line += str(text)

        root.clipboard_append(line)  # append new value to clipbaord

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However, I am unable to bind it to a TreeView object it seems; when I run the code, I get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
<class '__main__.App'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/user1/main_merged.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    lambda t=self.partitionsOpenDiskTree: self.copyTextToClipboard(self,t))
  File "C:/Users/user1/main_merged.py", line 70, in copyTextToClipboard
    textList = tree.item(tree.focus())["values"]
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'item'
```

If I try to print out tree type, I get that it's a  not a TreeView object. Any ideas on how I can get a TreeView object, so that I can figure out which item was selected?

Thanks!
-FF

Comment: please fix your indentation so we can check on "your" code

Comment: There seems to be a lot of extra code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve]. If your problem is with a `Treeview` binding, you only need a couple of widgets, the bind statement, and the bound funcitno.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the above comments.

Comment: It appears that `tree` is not what you think it is. What have you done to debug this? Have you examined the data right before calling `tree.item`?

Comment: t as input right before is a tree, when it is given to the bound function it becomes an __App__ type, which seems weird to me. I'm not sure why it would convert to a different type in the binding. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've also tried combos of lambda event, t=self.partitionsOpenDiskTree: self.copyTextToClipboard(t), where def copyTextToClipboard(self, t, event=None). Have also tried to pass in the event, then just not use. Each gives a different error. I've read posts about what to use, but nothing seems to work. In some other cases with buttons, def somefun(event, self, t) seems to work out, but not with trees for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently, taking out the self call seemed to work:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        frame = Frame(master)

        master.geometry("{}x{}".format(master.winfo_screenwidth() - 100, master.winfo_screenheight() - 100))
        master.resizable(False, False)

        self.leftFrame = Frame(master, bg="#DADADA", width=375, relief=SUNKEN)
        self.leftFrame.pack_propagate(0)
        self.leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=1)

        # This table (TreeView) will display the partitions in the tab
        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree = Treeview(self.leftFrame, columns=("#"), show="headings", selectmode="browse", height=23)

        yscrollB = Scrollbar(self.leftFrame)
        yscrollB.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.column("#", width=50)
        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.heading("#", text="#")
        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollB.set)

        # Bind left click on text widget to copy_text_to_clipboard() function
        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event, t=self.partitionsOpenDiskTree: self.copyTextToClipboard(t))

        # Adding the entries to the TreeView
        for i in range(3):
            self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.insert("", "end", i, values=(i), tags=str(i))

        self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.pack(anchor=NW, fill=Y)

    #todo: figure out where this is getting called and put in tree
    def copyTextToClipboard(self, tree, event=None):
        print(type(tree))
        # print(type(tree.partitionsOpenDiskTree))
        # triggered off left button click on text_field
        root.clipboard_clear()  # clear clipboard contents
        textList = tree.item(tree.focus())["values"]
        line = ""
        for text in textList:
            if line != "":
                line += ", " + str(text)
            else:
                line += str(text)

        root.clipboard_append(line)  # append new value to clipbaord
        print(line)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

0

Answer (score 1):

When you use `bind`, the callback function must have an `event` as its first argument, custom arguments should be put after. But as your callback does not need the event parameters, you may mask it with your lambda. So you have to change both the binding and the `def` of your callback:

```
self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event, t=self.partitionsOpenDiskTree: self.copyTextToClipboard(t))

...

def copyTextToClipboard(self, tree):
```

should solve the problem

Comment: I tried the above, which gives me the following error: 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/user1/main_merged.py", line 28, in <lambda>
    self.partitionsOpenDiskTree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event, t=self.partitionsOpenDiskTree: self.copyTextToClipboard(self,t))
TypeError: copyTextToClipboard() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

------(Not sure how to format so that it appears on multiple lines.)

Comment: Oops, I forgot to suppress the `self` argument in your lambda (which is automatically provided by Python). I've edited the answer, but I see that you have already found the correction by yourself.

Comment: The `self` argument explains why the interpreter tells you that the type of `tree` is `App`, because when you add `self` by hand it becomes the second argument, so it is linked to `tree`

Comment: ah yes. that makes sense.